# Reg-ex Examples in Parser Combinators

Tags: scala, parsing

I'm looking at a `Parser[Any]` for a wildcard grammar where only a word followed by 1 `*` parses succesfully.

Valid Examples:

- FOO*
- BAR*

Invalid Examples:

- FOO*BAR*
- BAZ****

I tested the following 2 `Parser[Any]`:

```
  def wildWithDollar     = """^\w+\*$""".r
  def wildTest           = """^\w+\*""".r
```

Testing them out:

```
  "ABC** with a `$`" should "fail" in {
    val result = parseAll(wildWithDollar, "ABC**")
    println(result)
    assert(result.successful == false)
  }

  "ABC** without a `$`" should "fail" in {
    val result = parseAll(wildTest, "ABC**")
    println(result)
    assert(result.successful == false)
  }
```

Both fail, yet the error messages are different:

```
[1.1] failure: string matching regex `^\w+\*$' expected but `A' found

ABC**
^
[1.5] failure: string matching regex `\z' expected but `*' found

ABC**
    ^
```

Is either parser acceptable since they both fail? If I used this `wildcard` Parser with other grammar elements, are there any potential problems with the `wildTest` parser as it's not explicit about a single ending `*`?

Comment: Unless I'm confused about what you are doing, you just need `\w+\*` without `^` or `$` - `parseAll` will make sure the whole string is matched.

Comment: I recommend having some "happy case" tests as well, to make sure it matches what you expect it to match.